# Ref as prop in Typescript in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

How can I push ref prop to the child component? I get an error:

```
'{ reference: RefObject<HTMLSelectElement>; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
  Property 'reference' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
```

I know it is something about React.FC<> and the generic function but I have no idea what type is it, what should I write between <> to work with refs pushed from another component.

*EDIT: I know I can use forwardRef but the point of this question is how can I pass ref using props.

```
 const typeRef = useRef<HTMLSelectElement>(null)
    const descriptionRef = useRef<HTMLTextAreaElement>(null)

    const onSubmitHandler = (e: React.FormEvent): void => {
        e.preventDefault()
        
    }

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Navbar />
            <Center width="100%" height="95vh">
                <Flex justifyContent="center" alignItems="center" width="50vw">
                    <FormControl textAlign="center" onSubmit={onSubmitHandler}>
                        <Input ref={titleRef} placeholder="Name for your recipe" />
                        <SelectType reference={typeRef} />
                        <Textarea ref={descriptionRef} placeholder="Description" cols={COLS} rows={ROWS} resize="none" />
                        <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
                    </FormControl>
                </Flex>
            </Center>
        </React.Fragment>
        
    )
}
```

child:

```
import { Select } from "@chakra-ui/react"

const SelectType: React.FC<> = (props) => {
    return (
    <Select ref={props.refProp}>
        <option>Breakfast</option>
        <option>Lunch</option>
        <option>Dinner</option>
        <option>Supper</option>
    </Select>
    )
}

export default SelectType
```

Comment: I guess the technique called [Forwarding Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html) could help in this scenario.

Comment: I know what you mean but for me using props is more convienient.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You simply need to define the prop types for your `SelectType` component.

```
const SelectType: React.FC<{ refProp: React.RefObject<HTMLSelectElement> }> = (props) => { ...
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=36&ssc=91&pln=36&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzksgGZwC+cpUEIcA5FKhgwFCiSy5wDKSAGyQZsAYSQA7GEijYAYkIAe86CFEQptAdgCSEsPixwAQoZgbsAFSSKYKZikrVa9AEQABNAAsUAaygoALT4wAD0DhiubGxoGoTwAIJgYABciCwwAHRyonAAvHAAFACU+QB8uGxwcLES8XAwwDBCZPkExK0APHAAEpYAsgAyegYwAKJCIJLwFYUS+AICxVU1cfAwAJ5gJEjkBUQ75N19Q-xCGBNIU1Jws-OLyyu19QAmSIRoUMBgjRqt+x1dnBjgNBtZbAkHJdrjMivcltFqs94BpePgAEYgJo9FASF5CKBtQpINLIdBZOSqMYAN2mxTS1IgwBe5Uq1WqSEyYGYtKkABFdigFjASojKGLkXBRAB5Qa8NoARgA3E81ohpQB1eUFZVi5gwfBQCRFFbVTpkjDZAIAcxhZVN7JwoQAVMCAHIoano+xwUJlZ2hCgOs3iKQyOAAd2ZMC8eVcCoADAmAKSuOBeJDAa1eGBxgCcAFZqV5XPb2eXgQobHAAFZERqkDbqMNSONoaYyNMoARZiQ6aQgQhtjtQNNRl4xuMFhPUiOl4MVzqUqBqDQwLQNGwwBI960SYdh0dwVEYrG5nAnzHY3H4mQUMsVx+dEaGODMUh5HCNZqHKhgAToEgXgQAIbxQHGHpTNQ0BwBsECGm+wjfEgaZ+guT5nMIMCWFsSCIaQAAKtBgJ+mzbGQVBoY+T7gnYDj4Z+bwfF8PzAH8ux-gB7bAaBMhxgKzHfL8EhprEAhDjgMpylQtARhJCCarwMnvMAABeSBxhIGgob6D7UeynSmDA5jGmRGmuIQp5NKWaJXjAnShEZJl6dRDnLqumggS55ZuUo3nAqEobSFALkORaFI2naYrLEGMRqphGA4dspIZNkoidHg75ERAqTpOSmRkNK6I1lhnQnHKghYdC0wVPeRLcjlhClHkFQ4Cs+qGsahQOp0CXwO+n4NWAhCZFlxH3gunQ5cJZTGA4vikCg8QOdNbESP5U2sRoZSDPgEjeCtW3rZNq3bXywASBIMiHTNJ1HWUaLJNdoSncdPmhH1D4xWwQA)

Comment: This is the answer I need!

Comment: Just what I needed

Answer (score 1):

In order to pass down a `ref` to a child component the technique called [Forwarding Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html) could be used which would help in this scenario, see from the documentation:

> Ref forwarding is a technique for automatically passing a ref through a component to one of its children.

Changing from `reference` to `ref` to pass down `typeRef` as:

```
<SelectType ref={typeRef} />
```

Then finally within the `<SelectType />` component using `forwardRef` as:

```
const SelectType = React.forwardRef((_, ref) => {
  return (
    <Select ref={ref}>
      <option>Breakfast</option>
      <option>Lunch</option>
      <option>Dinner</option>
      <option>Supper</option>
    </Select>
  )
})
```

In this way you don't need to add any type for `props`.

Comment: I know i can use forwardRef, but my question is pointing that is it possible to pass ref as a prop in react-typescript.

Comment: @Kay No it's not possible to pass without forwarding. The reason you can't pass `ref` to the functional component it because it's a keyword. You would essentially be setting the `ref` to `SelectType` component rather passing it in to `<Select>`

Comment: Without typescript I passed refs through props and it worked.